# Как устроен мьютекс?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

В первом потоке успешно лочится мьютекс и проводятся операции с разделяемым ресурсом. При этом второй поток пытается захватить этот мьютекс. Что происходит внутри мьютекса во втором потоке?

Вопрос с собеседования по С++.

Я ответил, что в мьютексе, возможно, имеется атомарная переменная на основе `std::atomic`, которая хранит что-то типа хэша от id процесса и id потока, и второй поток крутится в бесконечном цикле, считывая эту переменную, пока она не освободиться в первом потоке. Как только первый поток освобождает мьютекс, он записывает ноль в эту атомарную переменную. Второй поток считывает ноль, записывает в нее новый хэш и начинает работать с разделяемым ресурсом.

Мне ответили, что если бы мьютекс так был реализован, железо, на котором крутятся многопоточные программы, сильно перегревалось бы. То есть, мне намекнули, что мой ответ неправильный. Как на самом деле устроена функции lock() и unlock() в мьютексе?

Comment: второй процесс не крутится, он блокируется планировщиком ОС, то есть поддержка мьютексов это уровень ОС, а не программы

Comment: Вы в самом деле описали (конечно, нафантазировав о хэше) разновидность мьютекса, известную как [spinlock](https://www.definitions.net/definition/spinlock)

Comment: Павел, а что значит - поток блокируется?

Comment: это значит потоку ОС не выделяет процессорное время по причине блокировки, в данном случае на мьютексе, когда процесс разблокируется, то ему ОС начнёт выделять время. Аналогично процесс может быть заблокирован на ожидании чтения файла и по многим другим причинам

Answer (score 6):

Поток может перейти в ждущее состояние, и спать, пока его не разбудит другой поток.
Так ничего "греться" не будет.

К сожалению, такой переход в другое состояние сам по себе относительно долгий (на нынешних мейистримных железе и системах всегда связан с переходом в режим ядра). Поэтому перед тем, как осуществлять такой переход, полезно сделать хотя бы одну описанную в вопросе итерацию проверки атомиков. Или более одной в цикле.

Ожидание и пробуждение - сервисы операционной системы. Некоторые реализации системных механизмов включают и атомарную предварительную проверку.

---

Ещё уточнение про атомарную переменную:

- переход из "свободен" в "занят" - это не атомарное чтение и последующая атомарная запись, а одна атомарная операция. в терминах `std::atomic` это может быть `exchange`, `compare_exchange_...`, `fetch_and`, `fetch_or`, или `atomic_flag::test_and_set`
- попытки занять мьютекс при это лучше не делать как попытки чтения-и-записи в цикле, а всё же пытаться просто читать в цикле, и пытаться сделать атомарную операцию чтения-и-записи только после чтения "хорошего" значения.
- ещё между попытками чтения вставляют особую инструкцию с "семантикой спинлока", если таковая имеется для данной архитектуры. Это `pause` инструкция (`_mm_pause` интринсик) для x86. Делать она может много чего полезного такого для сценария; что именно по факту делает - зависит от процессора.
- переход из "занят" в "свободен" тоже будет не просто запись в реализации с состоянием ожидания, потому что надо проверить, нужно ли будить другой поток.

---

В Windows для ожидания могут быть взяты Mutex, Semaphore, Event, но в такой мьютекс не будет встроена атомарная переменная, её нужно прикрутить сверху.
Лучше сделать мьютекс из `CRITICAL_SECTION`, `SRWLOCK` или `WaitOnAddress`, в эти механизмы цикл с атомарной переменной уже встроен (кроме того, этот подход безопаснее и экономичнее в плане выделения ресурсов).

Реализация в актуальных Visual Studio (начиная с 2015) использует `SRWLOCK` на актуальных ОС, с откатом на запасный вариант на устаревших.

---

В POSIX мьютекс просто может использовать pthread mutex. В системах, где есть фьютексы, может использовать фьютекс.